# Generalization of a symmetric eigenvalue problem for linear operators on a Hilbert space

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory, spectral-theory

Let $A\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$. Which assumptions on $A$ do we need and how can we show that $$\max_{\substack{z\in\mathbb R^n\\|z|=1}}\langle Az,z\rangle\tag1$$ is attained at the unit eigenvector $z_{\text{max}}$  associated with the largest eigenvalue $\lambda_{\text{max}}$  of the symmetric matrix $A+A^T$ and the optimal objective value is the logarithmic norm of $A$?

A reference would be enough. What I would like to know further: Is there a generalization of this result to linear operators on a Hilbert space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 
\begin{align}
\langle Az,z\rangle&=\tfrac12\,\left(\langle Az,z\rangle+\langle Az,z\rangle\right)
=\tfrac12\,\left(\langle Az,z\rangle+\langle z,A^Tz\rangle\right)\\
&=\tfrac12\,\left(\langle Az,z\rangle+\langle A^Tz,z\rangle\right)
=\tfrac12\,\langle (A+A^T)z,z\rangle.\\
\end{align}
Now since $A+A^T$ is symmetric, the Spectral Theorem gives us that 
$$\tag1
A+A^T=\sum_j\lambda_j\,P_j,
$$
where $\lambda_1\geq\lambda_2\geq\cdots\geq\lambda_n$ are the eigenvalues of $A+A^T$ and the $P_j$ are pairwise orthogonal rank-one projections. Then
$$\tag2
\langle (A+A^T)z,z\rangle=\sum_j\lambda_j\langle P_jz,z\rangle.
$$
The numbers $\langle P_1z,z\rangle,\ldots,\langle P_nz,z\rangle$ are non-negative and add to $1$, so $(2)$ can be seen as a convex combination of $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$.

The only difference when you go infinite-dimensional is that instead of $\max$ you need $\sup$. Thus
$$
\max_{\|z\|=1}\langle Az,z\rangle=\tfrac12\,\lambda_1,
$$
and the max is attained at the eigenvector $z_1$ corresponding to $\lambda_1$.

When you go infinite-dimensional, you find two problems: first, the max need not exist, so you have to consider a supremum instead. More importantly, many operators have no eigenvalues.

Comment: In the infinite-dimensional setting, I'm interested in the case where $A=(\lambda-B)^{-1}$ for some self-adjoint contraction $B$ and $\lambda\in\rho(B)$. What can we say about the eigenvalues of $A+A^\ast$ in that case?

Comment: (BTW: What is the "logarithmic norm" of $A$ and how do we see that it is equal to $\frac{\lambda_1}2$)?

Comment: In the infinite-dimensional setting, it is perfectly possible that $A+A^*$ has no eigenvalues.  As for the logarithmic norm, there is a [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_norm) for it.

Comment: Yes, it's clear to me that it's possible that there are no eigenvalues (as for the multiplication operator on $L^2([0,1])$), but there should still be a generalization using the full spectrum in terms of the spectral theorem.

Comment: see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3383233/47771.