# Can we show that $\sup_{\left\|x\right\|_H=1}\langle Ax,x\rangle_H$ is attained at the supremum of $\sigma(A+A^\ast)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory, adjoint-operators

Let $H$ be a $\mathbb R$-Hilbert space and $A\in\mathfrak L(H)$. Consider the following optimization problem: $$\sup_{\left\|x\right\|_H=1}\langle Ax,x\rangle_H.\tag1$$
We may note that $A+A^\ast$ is self-adjoint and hence there is an unique compactly supported spectral measure $E$ on $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ associated with $A+A^\ast$. Now, $$\langle Ax,x\rangle_H=\frac12\langle(A+A)^\ast x,x\rangle_H=\frac12\int_{\sigma(A+A^\ast)}\lambda\:\langle E({\rm d}\lambda)x,x\rangle_H\;\;\;\text{for all }x\in H.\tag2$$

> In the case $H=\mathbb R^d$, as it was shown in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3382409/47771), the supremum in $(1)$ is attained at the unit eigenvector $z_{\text{max}}$  associated with the largest eigenvalue $\lambda_{\text{max}}$ of $A+A^*$ and the optimal objective value is the logarithmic norm of $A$. This is easily seen from $(2)$.
>
> **Question**: Can we infer a similar result in the general case?

We should be able to argue in the same manner by noting that $V:=\left\{\langle(A+A^\ast)x,x\rangle_H:\left\|x\right\|_H=1\right\}$ is bounded and convex and $$\sigma(A+A^\ast)\subseteq\left[\inf V,\sup V\right]\tag3,$$ but I'd need some help to figure out the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equation $(2)$ reduces the problem to $A$ selfadjoint. You also see from $(2)$ that $\sup\langle Ax,x\rangle\leq\sup\sigma(A)$. For the reverse inequality, fix $\varepsilon>0$. Then the Spectral Theorem (or the definition of integral, if $(2)$ is a given) gives you projections $P_1,\ldots,P_n$ with $\sum_jP_j=I$, and scalars $\lambda_1\geq\ldots\geq\lambda_n\subset\sigma(A)$ with $$\|A-\sum_j\lambda_jP_j\|<\varepsilon.$$
We may also choose $\lambda_1$ such that $|\lambda_1-\sup\sigma(A)|<\varepsilon$. Take  $x\in P_1H$ a unit vector. Then 
$$
\langle Ax,x\rangle=\lambda_1>\sup\sigma(A)-\varepsilon. 
$$
As $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary, it follows that $\sup\langle Ax,x\rangle\geq\sup\sigma(A)$.

Comment: Everything is clear to me except why we can assume that $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n\in\sigma(A)$ and that $|\lambda_1-\sup\sigma(A)|<\varepsilon$. (I'm using the definition of the integral to obtain pairwise disjoint $P_1,\ldots,P_n\in\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ and $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n\in\mathbb R$ such that $\int|\operatorname{id}_{\sigma(A)}-f|\:|E|({\rm d}\lambda)<\varepsilon$, where $f=\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i1_{B_i}$. In your description, $P_i=E(B_i)$. It's clear to me that $E(\mathbb R\setminus\sigma(A))=0$.)

Comment: Take $n>\tfrac1\varepsilon$. If $a=\inf\sigma(A)$, $b=\sup\sigma(A)$, define $$ B_j=[\tfrac {j-1}n,\tfrac jn]\cap\sigma(A),\ \ j=1,\ldots,n$$ and take $\lambda_j=\tfrac jn$.

Comment: (a) Thank you for your comment, but I still don't see why your choice of $\lambda_j$ should belong to $\sigma(A)$; unless $\sigma(A)$ is connected. (b) You've proved that the maximum objective value is $\sigma(A)$, but what can we say about the maximizer $x$? (It's obvious that if $\sigma(A)$ is finite, then the maximizer is any eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda=\max\sigma(A)$.)

Comment: Right, replace my last line with taking any $\lambda_j\in B_j$.

Comment: I'm really sorry, but then it's not clear to me why we know that $B_j\ne\emptyset$. BTW, you defined $a$ and $b$ but didn't use these symbols afterwards.

Comment: And it would be great if you could say something to $(b)$ as well.

Comment: Yes, it should have been $B_j=a+[\tfrac{(j-1)(b-a)}n,\tfrac{j(b-a)}n]$. And if $B_j=\emptyset$, then the corresponding projection is $0$ and nothing happens; you can choose $\lambda_j=32$, or any number that you like. As for (b), if $\sup\sigma(A)$ is not an eingenvalue, then there is max.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I'm not sure if I understand your comment regarding $(b)$. Since $\sigma(A)$ is compact, there is a $\lambda_\ast\in\sigma(A)$ with $\lambda_\ast=\sup\sigma(A)$. Now the question is if we can characterize the $x\in H$ with $\left\|x\right\|_H=1$ and $\langle Ax,x\rangle_H=\lambda_\ast$.

Comment: Yeah, there's no reason for that $x$ to exist in general. The set $\{\langle Ax,x\rangle:\ \|x\|=1\}$ is not always closed. It may be not-closed even for compact, positive, $A$.

Comment: Your set is at least convex. Are there some useful conditions on $A$ which ensure that it has a maximum?

Comment: Well, the conditions have to be either very explicit ("$\sup\sigma(A)$ is an eigenvalue")  or very restrictive ("$A$ is finite-rank").

Comment: Do you think we can say more in this specific case: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3387209/47771?